# Jaccard index: R not letting me convert raster to numeric?

Tags: r, raster, r-sf, r-raster, geo

I'm trying to calculate the Jaccard index for my data, which is for two presence/absence rasters (of two different species). I also have a third raster, that contains the overlap of the species ranges.

I want to calculate the Jaccard index, and have tried the code below

```
g1_binary <- as.integer(pg1_rast > tr1)
pg3_binary <- as.integer(pg3_rast > tr3)

# Find the overlap between the two rasters
overlap_binary <- pg1_binary * pg3_binary

# Convert the overlap raster to a RasterLayer object
overlap_rast <- raster(overlap_binary)
extent(overlap_rast) <- extent(pg1_rast)

# Calculate area of overlap, area of pg1, and area of pg2
a <- sum(as.matrix(overlap_rast)) * res(overlap_rast)[1] * res(overlap_rast)[2]
b <- sum(as.matrix(pg1_binary)) * res(pg1_rast)[1] * res(pg1_rast)[2]
c <- sum(as.matrix(pg3_binary)) * res(pg3_rast)[1] * res(pg3_rast)[2]

# Calculate degree of overlap
degree_overlap <- as.numeric(a / (b + c))
```

However, I keep getting the error:

```
Error in as.numeric(a/(b + c)) : 
  cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'
```

I've tried a million different things but don't seem to be able to convert my data to a number for the Jaccard index.

I've also tried to calculate it as:

```
overlap_rast/(pg1_rast+pg3_rast)
```

and although I don't even know if this would work, it's still giving me the same error that my raster can't be converted into a numeric value. Please help!

I tried the above, but it gave me the errors shown.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Example data (always include some when asking an R question, either by generating in code, or by using a file that ships with R. See the R help files for examples)

```
library(terra)
set.seed(1)
r1 <- rast(nrow=10, ncol=10, vals=runif(100))
r2 <- rast(nrow=10, ncol=10, vals=runif(100))
```

Solution

```
b1 <- r1 > 0.5
b2 <- r2 > 0.5
 
b12 <- b1 * b2

x <- c(b1, b2, b12)
g <- global(x, sum, na.rm=TRUE)[[1]]
J <- g[3] / (sum(g[1:2]) - g[3])
J
#[1] 0.3246753
```

This is assuming that all cells have the same size, as you do in your script. In that case there is no need to multiply `a`, `b`, and `c` with the constant cell size. This is fine for smaller areas, but it may be quite wrong in other cases.

To account for variable cell sizes you can do

```
a <- cellSize(b1, mask=FALSE, unit="km")
xa <- c(b1, b2, b12) * a
ga <- global(xa, sum, na.rm=TRUE)[[1]]
Ja <- ga[3] / (sum(ga[1:2]) - ga[3])
Ja
#[1] 0.3352633
```

Also note that you have `J = a / (b + c)` but that the Jaccard index can be computed as `J = a / (b + c - a)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone! I actually found from another really helpful page on here that you can change it by first converting to a matrix, then to a numeric, eg using as.matrix() then as.numeric() to sum everything up. Just in case that helps anybody!

Answer (score -1):

The Jaccard index calculation requires numeric values, and 'S4' objects cannot be coerced into numeric values using the 'as.numeric()' function.

To fix this error, you can extract the numeric values from the 'S4' objects using the 'getValues()' function from the 'raster' package. Try this code:

```
library(raster)

g1_binary <- as.integer(pg1_rast > tr1)
pg3_binary <- as.integer(pg3_rast > tr3)

# Find the overlap between the two rasters
overlap_binary <- pg1_binary * pg3_binary

# Convert the overlap raster to a RasterLayer object
overlap_rast <- raster(overlap_binary)
extent(overlap_rast) <- extent(pg1_rast)

# Get the values from the rasters
overlap_values <- getValues(overlap_rast)
pg1_values <- getValues(pg1_rast)
pg3_values <- getValues(pg3_rast)

# Calculate area of overlap, area of pg1, and area of pg2
a <- sum(overlap_values) * res(overlap_rast)[1] * res(overlap_rast)[2]
b <- sum(pg1_values) * res(pg1_rast)[1] * res(pg1_rast)[2]
c <- sum(pg3_values) * res(pg3_rast)[1] * res(pg3_rast)[2]

# Calculate degree of overlap
degree_overlap <- as.numeric(a / (b + c)) # Mind the formula!
```

Note: Jaccard index is the ratio of the size of the intersection of two sets to the size of the union of the sets. In this case, the size of the union is the sum of the sizes of the two sets minus the size of the intersection, hence the formula J = a / (b + c - a).